# Is there a way to get A & (B | C) in spring jpa method where expressions B and C are connected with same property?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

As result I want to have method with only one string argument (expression A).
But B and C expressions are with same property.
It means 'where date property is null or less_or_equal today'.

So, what I have is this method:

```
List<EntityObject> findByMyDateIsNullAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateLessThanEqual(Date myDate, String myString);

default List<EntityObject> findByMyDateIsNullAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateLessThanEqual(String myString) {
    return findByMyDateIsNullAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateLessThanEqual(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()),myString);
}
```

But, when I try to install in maven, because of test, I get this error:

```
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List MyItemRepository.findByMyDateIsNullAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateLessThanEqual(java.sql.Date,java.lang.String)! null
```

I know the other way is to use @Query with customized query but I prefer this one.
Is it possible?

Comment: No. Your only solution is to use an `@Query` as with a regular method it requires as many fields as you need in your query. It is probably even easier to write an actual query then to use a method which translates to a query. Generally speaking the query methods should be simple, if they become more complex they are unreadable, in those cases use an `@Query` instead.

Comment: You can try by modifying jpa method to something like this findByMyDateIsAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateLessThanEqual(Date date, String first,String second,Date datelesser)

Comment: I did it based on your idea...

Answer (score 0):

My colleague helped me, so...

First of all I forget findAll, because it could be more...

Second of all, I need for date IsLessThanEqual...

And third, I need 3 arguments. Only 3 because one is already defined in method name with 'IsNull'. So, I need 2 string arguments and 1 date argument

```
List<EntityObject> findAllByMyDateIsNullAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateIsLessThanEqual(Date myDate, String myString1, String myString2);
```

And then I have to call it with predefined value for date less or equal today date

```
    default List<EntityObject> findAllByMyDateIsNullAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateIsLessThanEqual(String string) {
    return findAllByMyDateIsNullAndMyStringOrMyStringAndMyDateIsLessThanEqual(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()),string,string);
}
```